# Criteria suggestion for review/low-quality-posts (or other quality features)

Tags: discussion, review, quality

I don't know if it's in, but it's a simple check that might bring out some bad apples:

```
if (Post.Title.Length > Post.Body.Length)
   Post.Quality--;
```

Just saying.

Comment: If you were doing something like that you could just look for posts with bodies under a certain length.

Comment: I created a quick query on SEDE so we can look at the kinds of questions this would be decrementing.  [Questions shorter than their title](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1068/questions-shorter-than-their-title)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (Matches(Post.Title.Words, Post.Body.Words) == Post.Title.Words || 
      SpellingErrors(Post.Title) > 1) {
    Post.Quality -= Math.Pi;
}

if (SecondsForUserToPickNextPost(Post) <= 10) {
    Post.FrontpageRanking -= 10;
}

if (UnimplementedNumberOfStarsSelectedByViewers(Post) <= 1) {
    Post.RemoveFromFrontpage();
}
```

Comment: I meant Question instead of Post but wanted to follow the lead.

Comment: I think Math.Pi is a little harsh. Maybe Math.E?

Comment: Seriously, `Matches(Post.Title.Words, Post.Body.Words) == Post.Title.Words` would not hit often, but when it would, it's a surefire disqualifier.

Comment: Concerning question instead of post, I figured title length on an answer must me always 0, so that's one less check. Final performance will be affected though :(

Comment: There's no parity between Question and Answer.  There are so many ways to improve a poor answer.  Just post another, everybody can.  Improving a poor question is hard.  There's only one.  Editing only goes so far, there are lots that are so vague that you can't do more than turd polish.  95+ percent of the edit suggestions btw.